# Why does this error appear the package created with compilation error?

Tags: oracle

I created table called Class and it was implemented as following:

```
create table "Class"
( 
"Class_id" number(10) primary key, 
"Tybe" number(5),
"Class_name" varchar2(10),
"Max" number(20)
);
```

After that try to create package but the following error appears the package created with compilation error:

```
CREATE PACKAGE PKG_Class IS

    PROCEDURE ClassAdd(
            ID_C in Class.Class_id%Type ,
            C_Type in Class.Tybe%Type ,
            C_Name in Class.Class_name%Type ,
            C_Max in Class.Max%Type );
 

    PROCEDURE ClassUpdate( 
        ID_C in Class.Class_id%Type ,
            C_Type in Class.Tybe%Type ,
            C_Name in Class.Class_name%Type ,
            C_Max in Class.Max%Type );

    PROCEDURE ClassDelete( 
       ID_C in Class.Class_id%Type );
    
    PROCEDURE ClassFind( 
        ID_C in Class.Class_id%Type ,
            C_Type out Class.Tybe%Type ,
            C_Name out Class.Class_name%Type ,
            C_Max out Class.Max%Type );

           
    FUNCTION FindClass(
       ID_C in Class.Class_id%Type
    )  RETURN Class%ROWTYPE ;
    
    FUNCTION Find(
        ID_C in Class.Class_id%Type ,
            C_Type out Class.Tybe%Type ,
            C_Name out Class.Class_name%Type ,
            C_Max out Class.Max%Type );
    ) RETURN BOOLEAN;
    
END PKG_Class;
/
```

Comment: Use `show errors` if your client supports that; or query the `user_errors` view to see the actual problem. But for a start, you're mixing quoted and non-quoted identifiers. I'd recommend you remove the double-quotes from the table creation.

Answer (score 2):

[TL;DR] Don't use quoted identifiers unless you have a specific business reason.

*(Then on line 34 of the package you have an extra `);` which should be removed.)*

---

You have columns using quoted identifiers in the table and these are case-sensitive.

In the package you are referring to then without quotes and they will be implicitly converted to upper-case and do not match the case-sensitive identifier of the table.

The simplest solution is to not use quoted identifiers in the table.

```sql
create table Class
( 
  Class_id   number(10) primary key, 
  Tybe       number(5),
  Class_name varchar2(10),
  Max        number(20)
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3b3b42717e1c91891185e672e842db39)*

---

The less-simple solution is to **ALWAYS** use quoted identifier for the columns and table whenever they are referenced in the package (and anywhere else) **AND** to use the correct case for the identifiers.

```sql
create table "Class"
( 
  "Class_id" number(10) primary key, 
  "Tybe" number(5),
  "Class_name" varchar2(10),
  "Max" number(20)
);

CREATE PACKAGE PKG_Class IS

    PROCEDURE ClassAdd(
            ID_C in "Class"."Class_id"%Type ,
            C_Type in "Class"."Tybe"%Type ,
            C_Name in "Class"."Class_name"%Type ,
            C_Max in "Class"."Max"%Type );
 

    PROCEDURE ClassUpdate( 
        ID_C in "Class"."Class_id"%Type ,
            C_Type in "Class"."Tybe"%Type ,
            C_Name in "Class"."Class_name"%Type ,
            C_Max in "Class"."Max"%Type );

    PROCEDURE ClassDelete( 
       ID_C in "Class"."Class_id"%Type );
    
    PROCEDURE ClassFind( 
        ID_C in "Class"."Class_id"%Type ,
            C_Type out "Class"."Tybe"%Type ,
            C_Name out "Class"."Class_name"%Type ,
            C_Max out "Class"."Max"%Type );

           
    FUNCTION FindClass(
       ID_C in "Class"."Class_id"%Type
    )  RETURN "Class"%ROWTYPE ;
    
    FUNCTION Find(
        ID_C in "Class"."Class_id"%Type ,
            C_Type out "Class"."Tybe"%Type ,
            C_Name out "Class"."Class_name"%Type ,
            C_Max out "Class"."Max"%Type
    ) RETURN BOOLEAN;
    
END PKG_Class;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=063776b0f210607fd85393992ae3936f)*