# Erorr in create Package Body

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I Created Table called Class then its Package called PKG_Class also created
it is OK.
But the execution of (Backage Body) give me erorr "Package Body Created with Compilation Erorr"

create table Class
(
Class_id number(10) primary key,
Tybe number(5),
Class_name varchar2(10),
Max number(20)
);

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PKG_Class IS

    PROCEDURE ClassAdd(
            ID_C in Class.Class_id%Type ,
            C_Type in Class.Tybe%Type ,
            C_Name in Class.Class_name%Type ,
            C_Max in Class.Max%Type );
 
    PROCEDURE ClassUpdate( 
        ID_C in Class.Class_id%Type ,
            C_Type in Class.Tybe%Type ,
            C_Name in Class.Class_name%Type ,
            C_Max in Class.Max%Type );

    PROCEDURE ClassDelete( 
       ID_C in Class.Class_id%Type );
    
    PROCEDURE ClassFind( 
        ID_C in Class.Class_id%Type ,
            C_Type out Class.Tybe%Type ,
            C_Name out Class.Class_name%Type ,
            C_Max out Class.Max%Type );

           
    FUNCTION FindClass(
       ID_C in Class.Class_id%Type
    ) RETURN Class%ROWTYPE ;
    
    FUNCTION Find(
        ID_C in Class.Class_id%Type ,
            C_Type out Class.Tybe%Type ,
            C_Name out Class.Class_name%Type ,
            C_Max out Class.Max%Type 
    ) RETURN BOOLEAN;

END PKG_Class;
```

////////////////////////////////

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Body PKG_Class IS
    PROCEDURE ClassAdd(
                ID_C in Class.Class_id%Type ,
                C_Type in Class.Tybe%Type ,
                C_Name in Class.Class_name%Type ,
                C_Max in Class.Max%Type )     
         IS
         BEGIN
         insert into Class
         values(ID_C, C_Type, C_Name, C_Max );
      Commit;
      END ClassAdd;
    
        PROCEDURE ClassUpdate( 
            ID_C in Class.Class_id%Type ,
                C_Type in Class.Tybe%Type ,
                C_Name in Class.Class_name%Type ,
                C_Max in Class.Max%Type )  
    
         IS
         BEGIN
         Update Class set C_Type = Tybe ,
                     C_Name = Class_name ,
                     Width_Pool = Width_P ,
                    C_Max = Max
                WHERE ID_C = Class_id ;
     Commit;
     END ClassUpdate;
    
        PROCEDURE ClassDelete( 
           ID_C in Class.Class_id%Type )
        IS
        BEGIN
        DELETE FROM Class WHERE 
        ID_C = Class_id;
      
    Commit;
    END ClassDelete;
    
        PROCEDURE ClassFind( 
            ID_C in Class.Class_id%Type ,
                C_Type out Class.Tybe%Type ,
                C_Name out Class.Class_name%Type ,
                C_Max out Class.Max%Type )  
    
     IS
     BEGIN
             SELECT Tybe, Class_name, Max
             INTO C_Type, C_Name, C_Max
             FROM Class
             WHERE Class_id = ID_C;
     END ClassFind;
    
        FUNCTION Find(
            ID_C in Class.Class_id%Type ,
                C_Type out Class.Tybe%Type ,
                C_Name out Class.Class_name%Type ,
                C_Max out Class.Max%Type 
        ) RETURN BOOLEAN
    
     IS
     BEGIN
     SELECT Tybe, Class_name, Max
     INTO C_Type, C_Name, C_Max
     FROM Class
     WHERE Class_id = ID_C;
     RETURN TRUE;
     Exception
     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
     RETURN False;
     END Find;
    
        FUNCTION FindClass(
           ID_C in Class.Class_id%Type
        )  RETURN Class%ROWTYPE 
    IS
    RECORD_C Class%ROWTYPE;
    BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    Into RECORD_C
    From Class
    Where ID_C=Class_id;
    RETURN RECORD_C;
    END FindClass;
    
    END PKG_Class;
```

Comment: First, do not ask [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70235071/why-does-this-error-appear-the-package-created-with-compilation-error) twice from different accounts. Second, please read answers and comments to that question, where you were pointed to execute `show errors` command or query `user_errors` table to understand the actual error. Third, at least try to debug your code and find a place where the error appears. Do not just post code listing with "debug it for me" question

Comment: I am beginner in oracle DB, can you help me where I can execute "show errors".

Comment: I am beginner in oracle DB, can you help me where I can execute "show errors". I use iSQL*PLUS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does this error appear the package created with compilation error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70235071/why-does-this-error-appear-the-package-created-with-compilation-error)

Answer (score 0):

In the body of procedure `ClassUpdate`, you update the values in the columns of table `Class`. In the `update` statement, you update the column `C_Max` to the value `Max`. That's the wrong way. The name of the column in the table is `Max`, and you want to update it to the value passed as an argument, `C_Max`. An assignment is one-directional: the right-hand side is assigned to the left-hand side. You can't turn around the "equality" since it's not really an equality, it only uses the same symbol.

If I am reading the rest of your code correctly, you are making similar mistakes for the other columns.

As an aside, `max` is the name of an aggregate function. While it is not *reserved* (which means you *may* use it as a column name), you still shouldn't use it as a column name; you will create confusion for yourself and for others who may need to maintain your code. And even if this is just for school (meaning, no one will ever maintain this code), it is best to form good habits.